# how many "likes" do i get by default when queuing FB graphAPi?

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I'm using Facebook Grap API tool

to simulate queries before I run them from my android app.

I want to get the users' likes and interests.

However i think the result doesn't include **all** the user likes and interests.

what is the default number it returns?

how can i ask for **all** the items?

[image]

Comment: @Octopus: Nope. The OP want to know how to _page_ through the results. If you look at the query in the screenshot, you will see that the context as well required results are two entirely different things. This is not a duplicate (_of that question at least_).

Comment: @SiddharthLele I have removed it, retracted the close vote

Comment: @EladBenda: If you were to scroll through the result set, you will notice that _work_, _interest_ and _likes_ are all seperated from each other with distinctly different _root tags_. At the end of each tag, if further pages are available, there will be a _"paging"_ tag which gives you the next set of results. Parse these and you should be good.